# getServiceLocator in utility class in zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, service-locator

I have a common class using for reusing functions of all modules. I have placed it in

```
Application\Service\Utility.php
```

Now I can create an object in my controller as

```
$utilObj = new Utility();
```

then call my function as `$utilObj->myFn();`

Everything working fine.

But I cannot get the `getServiceLocator()` function there (Inside myFn in Utility.php). Is there any way to solve this issue.
I need service locator there because I have to get the config data, doctrine management etc.

I haven't configured getServiceConfig in module.php.

Comment: Please read my two posts: https://juriansluiman.nl/article/139/zf2-why-a-service-is-not-available-in-your-constructor and https://juriansluiman.nl/article/143/collected-thoughts-about-the-dic-versus-sl-discussion to give you some insights about this problem

Answer (score 0):

I have this kind of class in my project.
The first option you have is to made a factory that include as a dependancy your serviceManager.

And then in your controllers (not recommanded) or in your module service inject or retrieve your utility class via your service manager with this

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Application\Service\UtilityClass')
```

The second solution is : your utility class is a service wich can implements this interface :

```
Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
```

And use this traits (be careful your PHP version has to be at least > 5.4)

```
Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;
```

This solution assure you in your service that you can use `$this->getServiceLocator()` in your class in any method you want to. Because any "aware" interface Zend framework 2 provides are designed with an initializer. It will automatically add some dependancies for you.